# Using Dropbox Sync in Android to open PDF

Tags: android, dropbox

I'm relatively new to Android and starting to play around with the Drop box Sync API for Android, and I'm having issues accessing the files from external applications.

I've currently created a link to Drop box for my app as discussed in the tutorial documentation: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android.  After linking, I display all the files from the the root folder in a list view.  From here, I want the user to be able to select an item in order to view a PDF with an external application i.e. Adobe Reader.

My issue is that when passing the drop box file reference as follows:

```
    DbxPath path = parent.getItemAtPosition(position));  
    Uri my_path = Uri.parse(path.toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(my_path, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

(Not surprisingly) Adobe is unable to open the document.

My question is if Drop box provides any sort of mechanism for actually accessing the files synced to the app folder, or do I have to make another copy elsewhere on the device in order to actually open the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *believe* you'll need to copy the file somewhere else to allow it to be accessed by other apps.